# AudioInputStream is not working

Tags: java, audio, javasound, javax.sound.sampled

I'm trying to play a .wav sound every time the user presses a button, but an exception gets thrown:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.createStream(PulseAudioDataLine.java:142)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:99)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioDataLine.open(PulseAudioDataLine.java:283)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:402)
    at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:453)
    at Uber.play(Uber.java:534)
    at Uber$5.run(Uber.java:340)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Here's the code:

```
//Play Audio File
public void play(String file) throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException
{
    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(file));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(inputStream);
    clip.start();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to get it working.
This is the code that I used. Keep in mind that I needed this just to play a short beep.wav sound. It seems to have some trouble with longer sound files. Let me know if it works for you guys and if you manage to play longer sounds with this code.

```
public void play(String file) throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException
    {

    try 
        {   
            AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource(file));
            AudioFormat format = inputStream.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
            Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(inputStream);
            clip.start();
        }

    catch (IOException | LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you pass the path of the file to the function play("path/to/file"); make sure that is the correct path and the reason why I'm saying that is because it can get very tricky when you package everything into a jar. Make sure you create a resources folder inside the root folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

It's something wrong with the file path you are passing. When I use your same code getting the file from a `JFileChooser` it works fine. Test this out.

Also see the [Javasound wiki tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for working with unsupported audio file types

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestAudio {

    public TestAudio() {

        JButton button = new JButton("Choose file");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

                File file = null;
                int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                }

                String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
                try {
                    play(fileName);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void play(String file) throws LineUnavailableException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(file));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestAudio();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @peeskillet, thank you for the reply. But if the path of the file was wrong, wouldn't that throw a "no such file or directory" exception?

Comment: Btw the code above gives me the same exception. I'm starting to think it's something wrong with the files itself. Weird tho since I've tried .mp3, .aiff and .wav all with no luck.

Comment: @Aci89 seems like you're right. I got a `FileNotFoundException`. I don't have much experience with audio. I was just testing out your method. I'm not sure what throws the `IllegalArgumentException`. The only other exception I was able to produce was an `UnsupportedAudioFileType` exception

Comment: @Aci89 yeah I'm not sure how to get those supported file types. The only ones I was able to get it to play with is `mid` `au`. I couldn't get it to go with `mp3`

Comment: @Aci89 may the [Sound trial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html) might give you some answers. Also take a look at the link I have above in my answer.